# Properly defined alias or function instead of `sudo nemo .`

Tags: sudo, alias, cinnamon, nemo

*OS: Linux Mint 18.x Cinnamon 64-bit*

Say, I would like to run `nemo`, the default file manager in Cinnamon, with normal `sudo`, and in current working directory:

```
sudo nemo .
```

Problems:

1. It shows different minor errors I don't care of, such as:

   ```
   (nemo:21081): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
   ```
2. After I close it, it takes exactly 30 seconds for the `gnome-terminal` to give back control to me.

---

Goal is to define a `bash` `alias` or `function`, which would not have these two, or any other negative aspects.

Additionally:

1. I would like it to give control back immediately, so that I could work with Nemo and Terminal independently.
2. I would like to be able to run it as it is for working directory or give it some directory as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my standpoint, the most effective method is to:

1. Use a [Subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), i.e. `(` and `)` at the beginning and the end of actual commands.
2. Background the command with `&` at the end.
3. Because we are running it as a background process, *normal* `sudo` would not do the trick, so we have to use the its graphical equivalent, `gksudo`.
4. IMHO this is not possible with `alias`, we need to define a `function` instead, because we need to check if the argument has been given and act accordingly.
5. The redirection of any output to the black hole (`> /dev/null 2>&1`) is a just good habit of mine. Not actually doing anything in such case as this one.

The function below fulfills my expectations, feel free to add your solutions.

---

## Working solution on Linux Mint 18.x

```
function sunemo {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        (gksudo nemo .    > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    else
        (gksudo nemo "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    fi
}
```

---

As you probably noticed, in Linux Mint 19.x `gksudo` has been removed.

## Working solution on Linux Mint 19.x

```
function sunemo {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        (nemo "admin://$PWD" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    else
        (nemo "admin://$1"   > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    fi
}
```